# Create data set from multiple column and compare it with another data set

Tags: php, mysql, database, compare

I have 2 tables in database: `table_1` and `table_2`.

`table_1` contains 3 column namely `a_id`, `a_zone`, `a_address`

`table_2` contains 4 column namely `p_id`, `not_use`, `p_zone`, `p_address`

The row numbers are not same in the 2 tables. I need to compare the "DATA SET" of the (`a_zone`, `a_address`) from table_1 with (`p_zone`, `p_address`) from `table_2`.

Let me give you an example:

```
Table1 contains:

a_zone  a_address
=================
1       8
2       9
3       6
4       9
5       2

Table2 contains:

p_zone  p_address
=================
1       8
2       9
3       6
4       9
5       8
```

Now I need to compare like this a_zone, a_address = p_zone, p_address or not.

I do not need to compare only a_zone with only `p_zone` or only `a_address` with only `p_address`. Rather, I need to compare the whole data combination. for my above example, I need to compare 18 with 18 [`a_zone`,`a_address` WITH `p_zone`, `p_address` ]

I'm stuck with it, and really need help. Please suggest me....:)

Comment: i am not sure if my answer is correct... i'll delete it if not... but how do you want the comparison to be made? row by row?

Comment: @ fthiella, Tank you for your comment. Yes, I want to compare it row by row.

Comment: oh! sorry :( I should have told you before how I need to compare the data. I need to store the output as bellow:

Comment: @kaild no problem! but do id match or not? in your example, (5,2) has the same id as (5,8) or not? if they have, i can update my answer and make it work, if they don't.... i don't think it's possible to answer with just plain Sql.. but you can use some php code

Comment: @ fthiella, thank you for your time :) The id is just the serial number here. As the 2 tables do not have the same number of rows the, id of table_1 and the id of table_2 is not same to all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified what data you wish to return so I have assumed a simple join.

Unless I am mis understandng your query I do not think that you need a union I think that you can do this with a single join:

```
SELECT *
 FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 
 WHERE (table_1.a_zone = table_2.p_zone) && (table_1.a_address = table_2.p_address);
```

This returns:

[image]

Comment: That is perfect!! And, now I need to specify the data which does not belong to table_1 but DO Exists in table_2 :). I think, I need  something like "INTERSECT"

Comment: I got it worked with this "SELECT a_zone, a_address FROM alvis_input UNION SELECT p_zone, p_address FROM panel_input" and successfully inserted to another table using this mysql_select_db("magic", $db_link);
$sql_1="INSERT INTO test (zone, address)
SELECT a_zone, a_address FROM alvis_input UNION SELECT p_zone, p_address FROM panel_input";
if (!mysql_query($sql_1,$db_link))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

Comment: Ok I am glad you found a solution. I am not quite sure how this answer relates to your original question but great to know you worked through to a solution. Good idea to accept an answer which ever got you working along the right lines a strong accept % makes it more likely that the community will join in with assisting you to find future solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, can't you just do two nested while loops like so:

```
$query1 = get a_zone and a_address from table_1;
$query2 = get p_zone and p_address from table_2;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    $a_zone = $row['a_zone'];
    $a_address = $row['a_address'];
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
        if($a_zone == $row['p_zone'] && $a_address == $row['p_address']) {
            do_something;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 left join table_2
     on table_1.a_zone = table_2.p_zone
        and table_1.a_address = table_2.p_address
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table_1 right join table_2
     on table_1.a_zone = table_2.p_zone
        and table_1.a_address = table_2.p_address
```

And then you can add some conditions, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 left join table_2
     on table_1.a_zone = table_2.p_zone
        and table_1.a_address = table_2.p_address
WHERE table_2.p_id is null or table_1.a_id <> table_2.p_id
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table_1 right join table_2
     on table_1.a_zone = table_2.p_zone
        and table_1.a_address = table_2.p_address
WHERE table_1.p_id is null or table_1.a_id <> table_2.p_id
```

But that depends on how do you need to compare the tables.